# Patching document.write on Edge and IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Here is a simple monkey patch for document.write which works in all major browsers but MS Edge and IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="first" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
        <script>
            var ifr = document.getElementById('first');
            var doc = ifr.contentWindow.document;

            console.log('Before patching:', doc.write);

            (function(doc) {
                var originalWrite = doc.write;
                doc.write = function() {
                    console.log('Patched');
                    return originalWrite.apply(doc, arguments);
                };
            })(doc);

            console.log('After patching:', doc.write);

            doc.write('<iframe id="second" width="300" height="250"></iframe>');

            console.log('After writing:', doc.write);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected behavior: doc.write after writing should be the same as after patching

Actual behavior: doc.write is undefined

Doesn’t work: Edge 18, IE 11

Works: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari

Snippet to reproduce:
https://jsbin.com/qutaxixeku/edit?html,console

Any ideas for workaround?

**Update 2019-11-19:**

Following Yu Zhou's answer. If I remove the patching logic altogether and log `doc` after writing, Microsoft Edge will show `<Permission denied>` error in HTMLDocumentPrototype as well. But if I log `doc.write` right after it, Microsoft Edge will show `function write() { [native code] }`

[image: Permission denied]

Moreover if I attempt to write to the iframe several times without patching, it will work fine on Edge:

```
doc.write('<div>One</div>');
doc.write('<div>Two</div>');
doc.write('<div>Three</div>');
```

[image: Multiple writes]

[Snippet](https://jsbin.com/zufohaquma/edit?html,console)

Comment: Why the IIFE....?

Comment: Without the IIFE doesn't work either

Comment: I know, but it is adding complexity

Comment: The idea was istead of the IIFE to create a function for patching all nested iframes. But it fails on the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a by-design issue of Edge and IE11. I**t's not suggested to call document.write more than once in an iframe in Edge**, even though it works with the native document.write method. Return to your issue, if you write to the iframe several times **after** your patching, Edge only shows one object:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="first" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
        <script>
            var ifr = document.getElementById('first');
            var doc = ifr.contentWindow.document;

            console.log('Before patching:', doc.write);
   
            (function(doc) {
                var originalWrite = doc.write;
                doc.write = function() {
                    console.log('Patched');
                    return originalWrite.apply(doc, arguments);
                };
            })(doc); 

            console.log('After patching:', doc.write);

            //doc.write('<iframe id="second" width="300" height="250"></iframe>');
   doc.write('<div>One</div>');
   doc.write('<div>Two</div>');
   doc.write('<div>Three</div>');

            console.log('After writing:', doc.write);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

We have reported the issue to Microsoft Edge Team but we're not sure if it'll be fixed in a foreseeable period for the new Edge with Chromium is coming.

Answer (score 0):

If you log `doc` after writing, you'll find that Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML) will show `<Permission denied>` error in HTMLDocumentPrototype:

[image]
The result is the same in IE. From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#Notes) of `document.write()`, we can see this note:

> Note: In Edge only, calling `document.write` more than once in an `<iframe>` causes the error SCRIPT70: Permission denied.

You can't call the write function more than once in an `<iframe>` in IE and Edge. If you call the function in other elements then it won't be `undefined`:

```js
var doc = document;
console.log('Before patching:', doc.write);

var originalWrite = doc.write;
doc.write = function() {
  console.log('Patched');
  return originalWrite.apply(doc, arguments);
};

console.log('After patching:', doc.write);

doc.write('<iframe id="second" width="300" height="250"></iframe>');

console.log('After writing:', doc.write);
```

```html
<p></p>
```